# "Android SDK command adb : Not found"

Tags: android, ruby, ruboto

I've installed Ruboto Gem and been following their wiki on how to proceed; however I keep getting this prompt every time I run the `ruboto setup` command:

```
Java runtime             : Found
Java Compiler            : Found
Apache ANT               : Found
Android Package Installer: Found
Android Emulator         : Found
Android SDK Command adb  : Not found
Android SDK Command dx   : Found
Platform SDK android-10  : Found

    !!! Ruboto setup is NOT OK !!!

Java runtime             : Found
Java Compiler            : Found
Apache ANT               : Found
Android Package Installer: Found
Android Emulator         : Found
Android SDK Command adb  : Not found
Android SDK Command dx   : Found
Platform SDK android-10  : Found

    !!! Ruboto setup is NOT OK !!!

Android tools not found.
Would you like to download and install it? (Y/n):
```

even after following through with the download and installation, the problem still persists. I had a similar problem with the `dx` before and I solved it in the PATH; but this one has no solution elsewhere.

Thank you!

Comment: do you have the platform-tools in your PATH?

Answer (score 0):

re-download the Android SDK, and you would find that file in:

```
adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130522/sdk/build-tools/android-4.2.2/

$ sg552@youku:/sg552/adt-bundle-linux-x86-20130522/sdk$ ls build-tools/android-4.2.2/
$ aapt  aidl  dexdump  dx  lib  llvm-rs-cc  NOTICE.txt  renderscript  source.properties
```

and then, add it to your PATH:

```
# your ~/.bashrc file or ~/.bash_profile : 

PATH=$PATH:$YOUR_ANDROID_HOME/build-tools/android-4.2.2/
```